# How to display WPF elements in one or more horizontal lines dependent on number of controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-7.0

My use case - I have horizontal layout for buttons (currently is StackPanel) with fixed height (lets say 40px). The buttons are laying in one row with each button height of 40. Buttons can be of different widths (dependent on the content - text). User can edit button text therefore width can change in runtime.

I need a way to handle cases when buttons overflow the available horizontal space without scrolling. Users want to have the layout change to 2 rows in this such a case. The buttons height would be modified accordingly (changed to 20).

I want it to be as easy as possible.

I dont want to do a custom control overriding OnMeasure/OnArrange etc.. But I dont want to use text length calculation in pixels which is never reliable and needs to take on account DPI of monitors and the window in question can move between monitors with different DPI etc..

Any practical solution?

How can I build a custom `WrapPanel` that can notify the children when they have overflowed onto a second row?

Comment: I don't believe there's any solution that's more straightforward than overriding `OnMeasure` and/or `OnArrange`. Even Denis Schaf's answer below would require that. What's the aversion to doing that? For a `WrapPanel` it's not particularly difficult.

Comment: Anyway if you look at the source for WrapPanel - https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/acdf9beaeadeef7ac466f226f4f2303fb26349d5/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/WrapPanel.cs#L6 - it's super simple. You could almost copy their AO/MO and just modify it to track when there's more than one row in a new DP. Then basically employ Denis' solution.

Comment: Just be wary of a potential condition where the response to the row count change could itself cause a row count change and you wind up in an infinte loop. As long as you're only altering the childrens' heights and not their widths you'll be fine though.

Comment: I have overriden OnArrange and it is working fine with triggers as @Denis suggested

Comment: Two can play this game ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76237784/display-wpf-elements-in-one-or-more-horizontal-lines-dependent-on-number-of-cont

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Custom Wrappanel-Class that sets the itemheight property if the number of rows changes:

```xml
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200">
    <WrapPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="WrapPanel">
            <Setter Property="ItemHeight" Value="40"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Rows" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="ItemHeight" Value="20"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </WrapPanel.Style>
    
    <Rectangle Fill="HotPink" Width="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="lime" Width="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="blue" Width="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Cyan" Width="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="50"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

All you have to do for this is write the wrappanel class based on a normal wrappanel that exposes the row count in a property.

Comment: How would you make a `WrapPanel` subclass that did this without overriding `MeasureOverride` and/or `ArrangeOverride`?

Comment: @EmperorEto you could just use the OnVisualChildrenChanged-Event and every time it fires calculate the width of all children and compare it to the Wrappanels ActualWidth property. Not the cleanest solution, but the request was to make things quick and easy, not perfect and reusable

Comment: Ah, sure, assuming the actual child dimensions have been calculated by that point then that'd work too.