# Display WPF elements in one or more horizontal lines dependent on number of controls?

Tags: wpf, .net-7.0

My use case - I have horizontal layout for buttons (currently is StackPanel) with fixed height (lets say 40px). The buttons are laying in one row with each button height of 40. Buttons can be of different widths (dependent on the content - text). User can edit button text therefore width can change in runtime.

I need a way to handle cases when buttons overflow the available horizontal space without scrolling. Users want to have the layout change to 2 rows in this such a case. The buttons height would be modified accordingly (changed to 20).

I want it to be as easy as possible.

Any practical solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be to subclass `WrapPanel` and override `ArrangeOverride`. You'd add a dependency property to track whether the panel has overflowed to a second row, which you could then use as a source for a trigger, and set this during the arrange pass.

**EnhancedWrapPanel**

```
public class EnhancedWrapPanel : WrapPanel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasOverflowProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "HasOverflow",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(EnhancedWrapPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata((bool)false));
    public bool HasOverflow
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(HasOverflowProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HasOverflowProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // Unfortunately the bulk of this is just copied from
    // the original WPF source since there's no way to 
    // inject into the arrange pass in a more subtle way.
    // For implementation of other referenced internal/private
    // structs and methods see
    // https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/0162cb1b509bafe8716ebff344d1170f663fdfee/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/WrapPanel.cs#L6
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        int firstInLine = 0;
        double itemWidth = ItemWidth;
        double itemHeight = ItemHeight;
        double accumulatedV = 0;
        double itemU = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? itemWidth : itemHeight);
        UVSize curLineSize = new UVSize(Orientation);
        UVSize uvFinalSize = new UVSize(Orientation, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height);
        bool itemWidthSet = !double.IsNaN(itemWidth);
        bool itemHeightSet = !double.IsNaN(itemHeight);
        bool useItemU = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? itemWidthSet : itemHeightSet);

        UIElementCollection children = InternalChildren;
        bool hasOverflow = false;

        for (int i = 0, count = children.Count; i < count; i++)
        {
            UIElement child = children[i] as UIElement;
            if (child == null) continue;

            UVSize sz = new UVSize(
                Orientation,
                (itemWidthSet ? itemWidth : child.DesiredSize.Width),
                (itemHeightSet ? itemHeight : child.DesiredSize.Height));

            if (curLineSize.U + sz.U > uvFinalSize.U) //need to switch to another line
            {
                arrangeLine(accumulatedV, curLineSize.V, firstInLine, i, useItemU, itemU);

                accumulatedV += curLineSize.V;
                curLineSize = sz;

                if (sz.U > uvFinalSize.U) //the element is wider then the constraint - give it a separate line                    
                {
                    //switch to next line which only contain one element
                    arrangeLine(accumulatedV, sz.V, i, ++i, useItemU, itemU);

                    accumulatedV += sz.V;
                    curLineSize = new UVSize(Orientation);
                }
                firstInLine = i;

                /** New **/
                hasOverflow = true;  
            }
            else //continue to accumulate a line
            {
                curLineSize.U += sz.U;
                curLineSize.V = Math.Max(sz.V, curLineSize.V);
            }
        }

        //arrange the last line, if any
        if (firstInLine < children.Count)
        {
            arrangeLine(accumulatedV, curLineSize.V, firstInLine, children.Count, useItemU, itemU);
        }

        /** New **/
        if (hasOverflow != this.HasOverflow)
            this.SetCurrentValue(HasOverflowProperty, hasOverflow);

        return finalSize;
    }        
}
```

**XAML Example**

```
<local:EnhancedWrapPanel>
    <local:EnhancedWrapPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:EnhancedWrapPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasOverflow"
                         Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ItemHeight"
                            Value="20" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasOverflow" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ItemHeight"
                            Value="40" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:EnhancedWrapPanel.Style>            
    <Button Width="200" />
    <Button Width="200" />
    <Button Width="200" />
    <Button Width="200" />
    <Button Width="200" />
    <Button Width="200" />
</local:EnhancedWrapPanel>
```

**Other Notes**
Be wary of a potential condition where the response to the row count change could itself cause a row count change and you wind up in an infinite loop. As long as you're only altering the children's heights and not their widths you'll be fine, but if you ever applied this in a different scenario you might need a check before setting `HasOverflow` to ensure that the arrange pass was not itself triggered by a change to `HasOverflow`.

Also thanks to Denis Schaf for suggesting the XAML part of this answer in the other question that was also closed.

Comment: it was me.. ignore it.. gonna delete misleading comments.. shouldnt have trusted google